# Cassandra token assignment for multiple DC cluster

Tags: cassandra, token

I am a little confused about the token assignment for multiple DC. When running nodetool ring, we can see all the tokens are/need to be different even for different DC's node. Does that mean all nodes in cluster form only one ring, or each DC's nodes form a ring in each DC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's right, the Cassandra token range spans the entire cluster, so there will only be one *primary* node responsible for any piece of data.

Managing data across multiple datacenters is handled by specifying the desired replication strategy, e.g. NetworkTopologyStrategy

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

Each DCs nodes form a ring in its own cluster. For multiple DCs, each DC has its own distinct partition range independent of each other. As @alec-collier mentioned NetworkTopologyStrategy will figure out the replicas for a partition within each DC.